# Neo4j How to add multiple values to the property of a node

Tags: nosql, neo4j

While i am creating nodes for one of the problem , I am stuck, after going through documentation I realised I couldn't find multi value property assignment to the node

**For eg: Node 1 have property Websites visit, since it cannot be a single website , how to add property to Node 1 "website" such that it can take two values like www.abc.com www.def.com**

```
node1["websites"] = "www.abc.com" "www.def.com"
```

Such that while accessing each property of a node each website in a node property can be accessed individually.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wouldn't it be better to do it the graph way and create a node for each website, than simply create relationship between the node1 and the websites nodes?

anyway, for modyfying arrays you may take a look at: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/neo4j/bY5GXWYpM1k

Comment: good idea , but nodes have some property to be used not just website

Answer (score 5):

You can use an array as the value of your 'website' property: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html

Comment: It should be OK. Your REST client (I imagine it's via REST that you access neo4j) should perform the conversion.

Comment: so How can I search for a particular condition in a node, for eg: how to find a node using neo4j rest client if website has www.abc.com or www.xyz.com , can you send me a link to a good rest client documentation

Comment: i am indexing ['http://www.abc.com/'] in one of the node ,
later i query z = index.query('hosts','http://www.abc.com/')[:]
and it returns me empty result

Comment: so even for a node with following properties ,
{'user_id': u'00042631907258101513', 'hosts': ['null'], 'follows': ['null']}
when i try : 
print index["user_id"]["00095006128319926033"][:]
or 
print index["hosts"]["www.abc.com"][:]
it returns empty list

Comment: You can try querying your indexes in the web console with Cypher or Gremlin. If it works, it means that the indexing is good, and your client code is to check.